# Getting error while executing SQL query to get result search by keyword using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

My requirement is when user will type letter inside text box at front end it will auto search from database and give the result accordingly. I have written some query but it gave me the following error.

> Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%P%) ORDER BY member_id DESC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

My code is given below.

```
$searchKey=$_GET['searchKey'];
$keyword = '%'.$searchKey.'%';
$sql =mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM  db_restaurant_basic WHERE rest_name LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY member_id DESC ");
```

My first search keyword was `p`.

Comment: You cant use placeholders without preparing the statement. You're just executing a plaintext query. Interpolation would do the job but might as well prepare the statement properly

Comment: Can you resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You want

```
$sql =mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM  db_restaurant_basic WHERE rest_name LIKE '$keyword' ORDER BY member_id DESC ");
```

or also you could do

```
$sql =mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM  db_restaurant_basic WHERE rest_name LIKE '" . $keyword . "' ORDER BY member_id DESC ");
```

(:keyword) is not going to pull in the variable for your keyword into the SQL syntax and also (:keyword) is not valid mysql

Comment: ok,error gone but its giving the wrong result.Those `rest_name` column value  not starting with `P` also are coming.

Comment: Satya Because you have % on both sides. If  you want only names starting with your keyword then remove the first wildcard %

Comment: This code introduces a SQL injection vulnerability. The OP was on the right lines with parameter binding - the correct answer was/is to use prepare/execute.

Answer (score -2):

Another approach,

```
$sql =mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM  db_restaurant_basic WHERE rest_name LIKE '".$keyword."' ORDER BY member_id DESC ");
```

It's better to use single quotes inside double quotes in relevant places when executing SQL queries.Sometimes you'll need to put single quotes for table name as well.Like this,

```
$sql =mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM  `db_restaurant_basic` WHERE rest_name LIKE '".$keyword."' ORDER BY member_id DESC ");
```

Comment: This code introduces a SQL injection vulnerability. The OP was on the right lines with parameter binding - the correct answer was/is to use prepare/execute.